# Modify file hex file to parser Python

Tags: python, hex

[image]

I have a file as follow:

I am looking a good way to:

- Modify to some friendly format to parser.
- After if I modify something.
- Reconvert to the same format.

My programming platform is Python usually, so I would like to get some feedback of someone with experience in this kind of files.

---

I have my file dumped in a list. So I can go to the position I wanted. But now what I need is to convert the hex value to ASCII or a UNICODE value. My code is:

```
import binascii

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    hexdata = binascii.hexlify(f.read())

print hexdata

hexlist = map(''.join, zip(hexdata[::2], hexdata[1::2]))

print hexlist
```

Comment: Your question is currently *unclear*. If the content of the file binary data that you dumped in hex or does the file contain hex strings? In first case, what prevents you to read the file as binary and dump it in hex, in the second what do you want exactly?

Comment: The file is containing string in hex. So, I want to read them with an offset, for example giving it a starting position with a lenght.

Comment: Still unclear. The current format is easy to parse. You should try to be more explicit on your requirements.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to open it. It is done. After that I have all the values in hexadecimal in a list. I will copy the code.

Comment: Then I have my file dumped in a list. So I can go to the position I wanted. But now what I need is to convert the hex value to ASCII or a UNICODE value.

Comment: I am still unsure about your real problem (hence a comment and not an answer). But assuming Python 2, you can revert to a string from `hexlist` with `''.join((chr(int(i, 16)) for i in hexlist))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import binascii

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
hexdata = binascii.hexlify(f.read())

print hexdata
hexlist = map(''.join, zip(hexdata[::2], hexdata[1::2]))

print hexlist
```

Comment: This is not an answer and should be an edit to the question (I've done the edit for you)